# Connecting to database error

Tags: android

I am trying to show the items from the database, but it just gives me the `Failure` toast...

These lines are mostly from tutorial and I just altered it a bit to suit my database. I don't really know what's wrong.

Any help will be greatly appreciated...

Here's the code :

```
package com.example.eksapp;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Message extends Activity {

    private JSONObject jObject; 
    private String xResult = "";    
    private String url = "http://10.0.2.2/testing/get_message.php";
    Button list;    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pesan);

        list=(Button)findViewById(R.id.list_message);
        list.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){

                //going to asynctask...
                new getting().execute();
            }
        });
        }

    private class getting extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            TextView txtResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.field_message);
            xResult = getRequest(url);
            try{
                parse(txtResult);           
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void parse(TextView txtResult) throws Exception{
        jObject = new JSONObject(xResult);

        JSONArray menuitemArray = jObject.getJSONArray("message");
        String sret = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < menuitemArray.length(); i++){
            sret +=menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("username").toString()+" : ";

            System.out.println(menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i)
                .getString("username").toString());

            sret +=menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i)
                .getString("subject").toString()+"\n";
        }
        txtResult.setText(sret);
    }

    public String getRequest (String Url){

        String sret = "";
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(Url);
        try{
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            sret = request(response);

        }catch(Exception ex){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Failure "+sret, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return sret;
    }

    public static String request(HttpResponse response){
        String result = "";
        try{
            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                str.append(line + "\n");
            }
            in.close();
            result = str.toString();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            result = "Error";
        }
        return result;
        }

}
```

The problem now, the items from the database show up in the `logcat`, not in the `field_message TextView`... The Logcat :

```
12-10 09:37:07.770: I/System.out(2671): marketing
12-10 09:37:07.770: I/System.out(2671): Testing 2
12-10 09:37:07.770: I/System.out(2671): marketing
12-10 09:37:07.770: I/System.out(2671): Testing
```

Comment: did you try to put try catch to see exception? it helps people you know!

Comment: what do you mean @clement? i dont really get it...

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Exception.html

Comment: Which tutorial are you using? This is not the right way to do what you are doing.

Comment: I've added the error log, and it seems something wrong with the json...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing networking on the main thread, which is not allowed in Android [since Honeycomb](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html). Use an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to do it in the background, and you should be fine.

More info here: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html

Comment: But, the error log didn't show anything about the `NetworkOnMainThreadException` error... Is it still possible that's the problem?

Comment: Yes, because you are hiding that error in the `Toast`. The `request` call returns an empty string, which in its turn gives you the exception you show.

Comment: Okay, I'll give you the progress after I figure out where to place the Asynctask...

Comment: Well, the JSON communication seems to work now. You didn't use the `AsyncTask` correctly yet (I am missing `onPostExecute` to do any UI work after the communication is done). Also, your question is *completely* different now. Try to understand what is actually going on, and ask a new question. In that new question try to be as concise as possible and remember, before you post a question: read the documentation (really read it!) and tell us what you have tried. We will not take you by the hand in how to create your program. Good luck!

Comment: Oh, yeah, i've already figured it out how to fix my project... I'm really grateful for your help on the `AsyncTask` problem... Thank you very much... And now, how do I delete this question...

Comment: No need to delete it. You could accept my answer and perhaps other people can benefit from your question.